# How to send response from another function without redirecting Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a route like this

```
Route::get('/downloadReport', 'ReportsController@downloadPdf')->name('downloadReport');
```

In `ReportsController` in the function `downloadPdf` I want to switch respond function as based on input parameter `reportType`

```
public function downloadPdf(Request $request){
   $id = $request->input('reportType');
    // some statements are there 
   switch($id){
     case 1: 
       $this->createReportType1($jobId, $cusName);
     break;
   }
}
```

and the response should be delivered to the user via this function

```
public function createReportType1($jobId, $cusName){
  $pdf = PDF::loadView('reports.reports',
            compact(
                'jobId',
                'cusName'
            )
        );

        return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
}
```

but I didn't get any output by doing this.. what is the reason and how should I achieve this without returning a value from `createReportType1` to `downloadPdf` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (I add  `return` keyword):

```
case 1: 
    return $this->createReportType1($jobId, $cusName);
```

Comment: without `return` statement  function `downloadPdf` don't return antyhing... :P it is trivial I know, however this bug is hard to notice - I make it sometimes too

Comment: ok but `createReportType1` function do a return.. so why isn't it enough. ? and before `downloadPdf` come to the end `createReportType1` returning right ?

Comment: `createReportType1` return result to function `downloadPdf` and this function can make many actions with that result - for example save it to DB and return ID, or just return whole result...